# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am having a beginner trouble about  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. My solution here is by removing the `s` on the `https` and it works but I think that not the real solution here.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.js"></script>
        <script>
        function arrayToTable(tableData) {
                var table = $('<table></table>');
                $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
                    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
                    $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
                        row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
                    });
                    table.append(row);
                });
                return table;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/csv_data.csv",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.here').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Your second `script` tag is malformed. It should be `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.js"></script>`

Comment: okay fixed it but that's not the source of the problem anyways thanks mate :).

Comment: Is  your frontend code also running on `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`? If so, you can just use `url: "/s.cdpn.io/162656/csv_data.csv` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX call needs to send a preflight request first to get "permission" to do this request. You can trigger this by adding the `Content-Type` header to the request with a value other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  contentType: 'html',
  url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/csv_data.csv",
  success: function(data) {
    $('.here').append(data);
  }
});
```

The code above will issue two requests: an OPTIONS request and a GET request. I suggest that you run the demo here (https://jsfiddle.net/bjyzs8y1/) and analyze the network tab to see the requests and responses.
[image]

Comment: I got these error on your https://jsfiddle.net/bjyzs8y1/ .. I think my google chrome is the problem here ?

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/csv_data.csv. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Try opening the demo in a private browser session.

Comment: @ines sorry for the late reply but yes, It worked! but only on incognito browser. but here's there response i get when I tested on regular chrome browser

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s605/sh/daa877e8-7452-4c17-95cc-2e157092a30b/08e5e9179b70a84218715b4793c470a8

Comment: I also tried your fiddle sample on another pc and it work .. how's that ? what wrong with my pc.

Comment: I imagine that Chrome is sending you a cached response. Try clearing the browser cache